# Connect to in-memory ElasticSearch from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can anyone please advise, what is the address if I am trying **connect to an ElasticSearch node** that is in-memory(just using the default config) **while using Spring boot** ? I am looking at something like localhost:port.

Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok, so it is **localhost:9200**, same as if running it externally.

Comment: this is not in-memory elasticsearch